# Firebase UI with Firebase Auth : Twitter not working due to R8

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I implement the connection with twitter on my app, everything works properly in debug mode but when I go into release mode (with activation of proguard so) I get this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Twitter provider cannot be configured without dependency. Did you forget to add 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:VERSION' dependency?
```

Before you ask, yes I put this dependence

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

and

```
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

i have already try to add manually the proguard rules from Firebase-UI that i have found here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/auth-proguard.pro

**EDIT** : Issue here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113513217

Comment: What version of FUI are you using?

Comment: Firebase Auth : 16.0.2 and 
FirebaseUI version: 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Related issues :

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113513217
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112230489

With proguard it's working fine, we need to wait the patch for R8